# What is the difference between makeFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder?

Tags: macos, nstableview

I just spent ages trying to work out how to keep the focus in an NSTableView column after deleting a row, rather than just keeping a selection. I did it like this:

```
[[myTableView window]makeFirstResponder:myTableView];
```

Why does the code above work, but the code below doesn't?

```
[myTableView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-makeFirstResponder:` is a *request* to the window that it make the specified responder its first responder. `-becomeFirstResponder` is a *notification* to a responder that it is about to become the first responder. It doesn't inherently cause a state change; it gives the receiver a chance to react to a state change that was caused by `-makeFirstResponder:`.

You should not call `-becomeFirstResponder` (except, possibly, to call through to `super` in an override). The framework calls it as necessary.